# Can I change the WSL terminal background color from the own terminal command line?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, colors

I use multiple WSL Ubuntu terminals from which I connect to different remote machines. It can get messy when I have many windows open to distinguish which window is for each machine, so I change the background color for the different windows and thus it's easier to identify on which remote machine I'm in.
I change the bg color with right click on the window top, -> properties -> colors -> screen background.
But this is getting tedious for every time I open a new window and I want to change the color.

I'd like to have scripts on the command line e.g. `set_red_bg`, `set_blue_bg` and so on. I tried to find instructions, but I only found for changing PS1, or LS_COLOR.

Is this actually doable? As I currently change the bg color from the Windows terminal options, I'm afraid the bg color for the terminal cannot be controlled from the Ubuntu shell, can it?

Answer (score 2):

While you can't directly control the background color from the Ubuntu shell itself, you can set up separate Windows Terminal profiles for each remote machine, each with its own preferred background color. Open new terminals directly with the desired profile using `wt -p <profile_name>`.

You can download the Windows Terminal app from the Microsoft Store.